# Irregular verbs: differences between BrE and AmE

Tags: verbs, irregular

I've just found BrE sneak/sneaked/sneaked and
AmE sneak/snuck/snuck.

Are there more of these deviations?

Generally, lists of irregular verbs in grammars are so poor that they show only half of what there is to know.

PS I see there is an article on the verb form snuck on the Internet.
["snuck" in AmE](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1931)

Comment: Spell is much the same, spell/spelt/spelt and spell/spelled/spelled. All those that end in a 't' form I think are 'ed' in American English (burnt, knelt) but I'd say British English is happy with either spelling.

Comment: @Frank  That is a known fact and indicated in grammar lists.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, do you mean it's unusual for the English version to be 'ed' while the American version is not ?

Comment: @Frank  I would say it is almost normal that you find for "dreamt/leant" dreamed/leaned in AmE.

Comment: I think that's what I mean, it's normal for the English version to be very irregular (kneel-knelt), while the American version is often quite regular (kneel-kneeled) but in the case of sneak, the English version is regular (sneak-sneaked) but the American version is irregular (sneak-snuck).

Comment: I'll just throw in dived / dove as the past simple of dive. I should think 'dove' is becoming more accepted in the UK, and that 'dived a cave/wreck' sounds incongruous. There's also speeded/sped. Here in the UK, I'd always use 'He speeded up when he reached the motorway' but 'He sped along the motorway'.

Comment: I've never heard a person say 'dove', unless they were referring to the bird.

Comment: @WS2 It's not a homophone, of course. You've obviously spent more time  watching Bill Oddy than [Hans Hass](http://www.divenewsnetwork.com/index.php/columns/dnncolumns/pioneers-series/1986-legendary-diver-hans-hass-passes-at-age-94) ['Starting in 1938 when he met and dove with another legend, Guy Gilpatric ...'] or Jacques Cousteau. Or their younger counterparts. See eg [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+dived%2Che+dove&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20dived%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20dove%3B%2Cc0) for increased UK usage.

Comment: See the section on verb morphology [2.2.1] in the Wikipedia article on [Comparison of American and British English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_American_and_British_English).

Comment: Edwin Ashworth, using *dove* to mean *dived*, is not exactly common, in the UK. I have not heard it.

Comment: If you read American novels you fill find "dove".

Comment: @Tristan r Google Ngram data might not be too reliable, but I'll take it over an unsubstantiated 'I've never heard...'. The relative frequencies in their 2000 British corpus for he dived : he dove were 4:1. Not exactly uncommon (in comparison).

Comment: Yes, you can take Ngram data but, it's not a substitute for experience of real life in the real world, outside the internet. In that real world, I have not heard *dove* used by British people. If it's used in the UK, it must be very rare.

Comment: The few times that I have heard the word, it was Americans who used it. Those times were memorable because, the word was so very different from *dived*, which is normally used in the UK. It was confusing why they used that, because, it was unheard of and therefore new to me, living in England, in the UK. The fact is, it is not exactly in everyday use by most people in this part of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Usage note on Snuck:

First recorded in writing near the end of the 19th century in the U.S., snuck has become in recent decades a standard variant past tense and past participle: Bored by the lecture, we snuck out the side door. snuck occurs frequently in fiction, in journalism, and on radio and television, whereas sneaked is more likely in highly formal or belletristic writing. snuck is the only spoken past tense and past participle for many younger and middle-aged persons **of all educational levels in the U.S. and Canada.** It has occasionally been considered nonstandard but is so widely used by professional writers and educated speakers that it can no longer be so regarded.

Usage note on irregular verbs:

**American English** normally uses the regular form, while British English tends to favor the irregular. In other cases, such as dive (dived vs. dove) and sneak (sneaked vs. snuck), the opposite is true. Australian, New Zealand and South African English tend to follow the British practice, while Canadian English often sides with the American usage.

Source: Webster Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

As it implies in the article you reference, for sneaked/snuck, snuck really is still pretty much "non-standard" usage. To say that this is standard American usage (except in casual speech) is really not correct. Yet.

See the usage tables in the article for the actual proportions depending on the media that were reviewed.

So for verb tense differences between US and non-US English, I would say there are *very few* beyond slang words. And would probably still be best-suited to be compiled as part of a list on differences in US/non-US vocab in general.